# How to trigger onPause programmatically in android activity

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I am trying to work out how I can simulate pausing an activity for debugging my app. I want onPause to be called but NOT onStop. I just want to try a pause resume cycle and am looking for some code i can call (e.g. after a button press) to trigger this.

Any ideas how?

I have seen people suggest pressing the home button in other threads but when I do this is stops the app and calls onStop as well as onPause so it isn't quite what I was looking for.

Comment: Why do you not want onStop() to be called? There will not be a real life situation where only onPause() gets called...

Comment: pretty sure onStop always gets called after onPause. take a look at the lifecycle of an activity http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Taken from this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html): The easiest is to add a semitransparent activity on top of your activity. I did the test myself and `onStop` is not called indeed:

The transparent activity:

```
public class TransparentActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.transparent_layout);
    }
}
```

any simple layout can be used for transparent_layout, but the tricky part is in the Manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".TransparentActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
        </activity>
```

where in styles.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Then in starter activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.btnNext).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, TransparentActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d("TSTAct", "#onPause");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d("TSTAct", "#onStop");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("TSTAct", "#onResume");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("TSTAct", "#onStart");
    }
}
```

When opening the `TransparentActivity` I can see in the Logcat only:

```
07-10 23:35:28.323: D/TSTAct(27180): #onPause
```

no `onStop` call.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go - I tried something similar by making a dialog that displayed over my screen and that failed but i didn't make a separate activity for that

Comment: Mr.gunar has summed it up. but I just want to say that not all semitransparent activity will call onPause. Such as, Dialog, because dialog use current activity's context. I hope I clarified it a bit.

Comment: Ok tried it and that worked for me so thanks. I was rather hoping there was a way to just do it in a line or so without making gui elements and activities. So I might also have a look at this Instrumentation class that I found today (I'm new to Android) and see about doing it from there.

Comment: You asked how you could simulate this in order to debug the app ... you didn't mention any TDD. But if you go on that path, you will find it indeed that it's easier that way. You'll just spent some time in order to accommodate with TDD.

Comment: Yes I was hoping I could do it in one or two lines without TDD (which is another matter entirely). At least your transparent fragment suggestion does do what I need when not in a test environment and i can't find a better way

Comment: This did not trigger onPause() method as asked in the question (atleast in my case), it just executes two Activities in parallel. But the answer does what you say...

Answer (score 2):

Simple way, From Mainactivity i will call another activity using Intent. In Manifest i will define as

```
    <activity android:name=".AnotherActivity"
              android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog" >
    </activity>
```

Means for another activity i will add style as "Theme.AppCompat.Dialog" means this will looks as Dialog.

From Main activity if you call this using Intent , then "AnotherActivity" will show as Dialog , It will come in on top of Main activity, that time main activity will be in onPause state (It will not call onStop state of MainActivity)

Answer (score 2):

1) define a method.

```
public static Instrumentation callLifeCycleMethod()
{
   return new Instrumentation();
}
```

2) call method.

```
callLifeCycleMethod().callActivityOnDestroy(MainActivity.this);
```

or

```
callLifeCycleMethod().callActivityOnPause(MainActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to debug what happens with onPause and onResume is to make use of the Android test framework. In an activity test you can get an Instrumentation object and then trigger pause and resume:

```
import android.app.Instrumentation;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

public class LaunchActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<LaunchActivity> {

    private LaunchActivity launchActivity;

    public LaunchActivityTest() {
        super(LaunchActivity.class);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {

        super.setUp();
        launchActivity = getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {

        super.tearDown();
    }

    public void testPause() {

        Instrumentation ins = getInstrumentation();
        ins.callActivityOnPause(launchActivity);
        assertEquals(true, true);
        ins.callActivityOnResume(launchActivity);
    }

}
```

Note that I am just using a dummy assert here. As an aside I am not yet sure how i can assert that the methods were called in Java

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to call the private method performPause in Activity using reflection.
Something like this should work in principle:

```
Method method = myactivity.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod("performPause");
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(myactivity);
```

Note I have yet to test it