# How can I trigger onPause and onResume?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-lifecycle

On the click of a button, I want onPause to be called. On clicking back/after a time interval, I want onResume to be called.

I find that system alerts, dialogs etc. do not call onPause and onResume on show and cancel.

I need to do this to verify a functional test. If i show a transparent activity, it's lifecycle methods would be called which would contradict what I am trying to test.

I only want to verify onPause and onResume on my current activity. Is this possible?

Comment: I think it's bad idea to call onPause. It looks like you have architechture problem in your code. Activity lifecycle doesn't depend on style (transparent or common activity) and calls always. Dialogs are the same.

Comment: On the click of a button, I want onPause to be called....are you sure what you are asking?

Comment: I want to bring up a view - an image/dialog/alert on the click of a button in my activity which will cause onPause() to be called.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to trigger onPause programmatically in android activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579941/how-to-trigger-onpause-programmatically-in-android-activity)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new transparent (or partially transparent) `Activity` to trigger `onPause`. Simply adding a `View` won't do anything.

Then, hitting back, or `finish`-ing the newly created transparent `Activity` will trigger the `onResume` method.

If you want to test `onStop` functionality in addition to `onPause`, you'll want your new `Activity` to be opaque and the full screen size.

You should test it this way -- let the Android system trigger these methods to be called, instead of manually running them. Hence, you can let a button click launch the new `Activity`, then either hit back to close it, or add a button to the new `Activity` to `finish` it.