# How can I manually trigger my Android onPause() method to test it?

Tags: android, android-activity, onpause

I would like to manually test that the Android app I am writing works correctly when paused. **What can I do through the Android GUI to cause the `onPause()` method to be called without causing `onStop()` to also be called?**

I've tried pulling down the notification bar and receiving a phone call, but neither causes `onPause()` to be called.

I would like to find a non-programatic solution that works for multiple versions of Android through the GUI, with or without phones, because I am teaching a class full of students using different devices.

Note that I am not asking how to tell *if* my `onPause()` method is called. I am asking what I can to do cause it to be called, without modifying my application.

Comment: you can use logs for this.

Comment: you can have Snack bar or toast message.

Comment: @santoshkumar Yes, I can have it display a toast, but my question is what can I do that will cause the onPause() method to be called, not how do I test whether the method has been called. I'll try making it clearer.

Comment: push application to background onpause will be called.

Comment: @santoshkumar I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by pushing the application to the background.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger onPause programmatically in android activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579941/how-to-trigger-onpause-programmatically-in-android-activity)

Comment: @santoshkumar Pushing the application to the background also causes onStop() to be called.

Comment: Thanks @akash93, but I don't want to do it programmatically. I want to do it through the device GUI.

Comment: @espertus Check the accepted answer for that question. It will trigger onPause on click of a button

Comment: @akash93 Yes, but it requires modifying the application under test.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible then.. Without modifying the application code `onStop` is always going to be called after `onPause`

Comment: @akash93 `onStop` is usually called after `onPause`, but I found a way (below) otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. I got the idea from a picture in the book [Head-First Android Development](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920029045.do).

1. Install [Any Do](http://www.any.do/).
2. Create a task.
3. Set an alarm for a few minutes in the future.
4. Start the app under test.
5. When the alert comes up, my app gets partly obscured, and its `onPause()` method gets called. If I click on the Dismiss icon, my app resumes without its `onStop()` method having been called.

[image: Picture showing app partly obscured by Any Do alert]

Answer (score 0):

You could call it programmatically.

Or simply start with intent a different activity.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to do it without modifying the app under test.

Comment: As you wish but it should help you test it. If I were you I would add a little button by the bottom-right that through OnClick Invoking a starting of a demoActivity.

Answer (score 0):

This can be one way of doing it in application.

```
  @Override
    protected void onPause () {
        super.onPause();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Paused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop () {
        super.onStop();
        Toast.makeText(this, "stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Other way you have is to open any Activity/Application using intent.

Comment: Thank you, but I'd like to know how to cause my onPause() method to be called, not how to tell whether it is called.

Comment: you have square button in android phone which is used to push app in background once application is not visible it will cause on pause state

Comment: you can open Second activity from first one in that case first activity will go to background and second will come up onPause of first will b called.

Comment: @santoshkumar But those things will also cause onStop() to be called and the OP made it clear that they don't want that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation paused state occurs, if an activity has lost focus but is still visible (that is, a new non-full-sized or transparent activity has focus on top of your activity), it is paused. A paused activity is completely alive (it maintains all state and member information and remains attached to the window manager), but can be killed by the system in extreme low memory situations.

Hence if you attend a call obviously your call screen will come at the stack and it will call onStop() of the previously running activity.

So if you want only onPause() to be called you should open a new non-full-sized or transparent activity.

Comment: Can you recommend an easily available non-full-sized or transparent activity, and how would I start it non-programmatically without navigating away from the application under test and causing its onStop() method to be called?

Comment: Simplest option would be getting a notification from a different application, when your current application is open. For example, say if you get a call to your phone where your app is running, or say you get a whatsapp notification. Then onPause() will be called. Once you open the notification, onStop will be called. But with just the notification only, onPause() will be called.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up doing something like that.

Comment: Cool. Showing a dialog is a better way to show a larger audience.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an alert dialog to call the `onPause()` without calling `onStop()`.

But the important point to note is to create the alert dialog as an activty.

This can be done as follows:

Create a new activty class called *dialog* extending `AppCompatActivty`, and also add it to `AndroidManifest.xml` as shown:

```
public class dialog extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //set appropriate layout
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Add to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application>
....
    <activity
                android:name="dialog"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"></activity>
</application>
```

Add the following to `onCreate()` method of MainActivty.java:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dialog.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you, but part of my goal was to not have to modify the app under test.

Comment: As far as i know, there r two methods to achieve this - by creatin an alert dialog or by startin a new transparent activity on the existin activity, both of which requires u to alter the code. If u simply press any of the hardware buttons(back, home or overview) on device, it wil cal both onPause() and onStop() methods.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in 29 API notification may not work.
For manually calling methods onPause()/onResume() should hold the home-button